# designing a 1-2-3 step guide

Tags: website-design

Being primarily a web developer, I'm always looking for tools or guidelines that make it hard for me to mess up the user experience. I'm looking to create a 1-2-3 step guide. I'm thinking that it should be small boxes that are all visible at the same time, containing maybe a cropped picture and some text, but I'm open to suggestion or will take what you've got.

Is there any web tools out there that can help me create such a guide either some kind of generator or some free css templates that demonstrate it.

So what I'm looking for is some guidelines to how to present in a pretty and presentable way, at best exemplified by a reference, and possible also a reference to a website tool that will help me to generate a guide that looks good.

I'm talking about usable examples like:
http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2009/05/simplifying-website-usability-the-3-step-approach/

Comment: Could you add more detail about your situation/application?  As currently written, I'm unsure what you're looking for... best practices for presenting a 1-2-3 step guide to your users? Or something else?

Comment: @Daniel Newman - I updated the question, I hope it makes more sense now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://designinginterfaces.com/patterns/wizard/

I agree with the comments made above - the question is too large to answer. You should start to build your wizard and then ask about more specifik details, for example "where should I place the 'next' button"...

Comment: Thank you for your answer - actually I wasn't thinking of creating it as a wizard, but maybe I should.

Comment: I was just thinking that maybe someone had pointers as to where to put "3-step get started with benefitting from this website" and what designs are best (vetical/horizontal, bubble/square, overlapping/separated etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there are any tools for this, but if you are familiar with html, css & a bit of js/jquery then this could help:

https://codepen.io/designify-me/pen/qrJWpG

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad. You can always look around the internet for great wizard/stepped UI workflows. There are countless collections of UI/UX patterns for this exact topic.

Keep in mind that there are always difference requirements and UX expectations based on device and intended use.